# How will the OpenID change affect me?

Tags: support, login, openid

I have read various documents and still don't understand the open-ID change.

What exactly is open-ID and how do the various parts of Stack use it?

I am an occasional user of various parts of Stack and sometimes log in directly via email and password and sometimes via Yahoo. I am not a Facebook member and don't like using my Google identity more than necessary as it starts taking over my computer.

Do I need to take any action now?

How will the change affect me in future?

Answer (score 2):

The email and password login should always work. The Yahoo login is openid and will no longer work after the change.

Openid *used* to be a vaguely standard, common way to let you share login credentials between sites. Support's spotty now (replaced by Oauth and Oauth2) and implementations vary enough that folks at SE felt the technical debt was too great. Its only used to log in, and nothing much else.

Unless SE emailed you about this - meaning you're logging in over just openid, you should be fine, and no action needs to be taken.